# How to store last numbered part of current page url in php variable

Tags: php, html

My page url just like that
http://wallpapers.wapego.net/main.php?ses=SuNpjmgtjmN7&f=3153038

now i want to take a part of current url that is 3153038 and store it as php integer variable

Comment: read php basic from w3schools

Comment: No, DO NOT use w3schools. Read the officicial PHP reference on www.php.net. Many examples and explanations on w3schools are simply incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

`$_GET['ses']` will give you 'SuNpjmgtjmN7' and `$_GET['f']` will give you '3153038'

Check [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use a GET super global or REQUEST super global variable.
ex -

```
$value = $_GET['f']; or $value = $_REQUEST['f'];
```

$_GET super global uses for get values from the URL. $_POST super global uses for put values to the server. I hope you understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Provided your calling this URL in a 'get request' the value of 'f' will be in the $_GET array.

But the best way to store this as an integer value would be to parse it through intval()

```
$value = intval($_GET['f']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to do it like this..

```
intval($_REQUEST['f']);
```